# C++, suitable data model, polymorhpism

Tags: c++, model, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am looking for the suitable data model. Suppose A to be a class with the attribute a with a simple computation method getat():

```
class A{       
  protected:
      int a;
  public:
      int getat(int t){return f(a,t);} //Some calculation
      virtual int getbt(int t)=0; //b defined in B, C
      virtual int getct(int t)=0; //c defined in C
      virtual ~A()=0; 
};
```

Analogously, B, C are the derived classes with the attributes b, c (but C is not a kind of B):

```
class B{       
  protected:
      int b;
  public:
      virtual int getbt(int t){return f(b,t);} //Some calculation
      virtual int getct(int t){return f(b,t)}; 
      virtual ~B(){}; 
};

class C{       
  protected:
      int b, c;
  public:
      virtual int getbt(int t){return f(b,t)};
      virtual int getct(int t){return g(c,t)};
      virtual ~C(){};
};
```

Considering the polymorphism I would like to use store objects of the parent class A:

```
std::list <A>;   //Abstract class, impossible
std::list <A*>;  //Possible, but problem with the destructors
std::list<std::shared_ptr<A> >; //The best solution?
```

My questions:

1] Is the proposed data model with the pure virtual functions reasonable?

2] Does is makes sense the removal of abstraction?

```
class A{       
  protected:
      int a;
  public:
      int getat(int t){return f(a,t);}
      int getbt(int t){}; 
      int getct(int t){}; 
}
```

Subsequently, std::list  is allowed.

3] If a polymorphism is required, which method of storing of A objects is recommended?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What problem with the destructors? Lack of virtual destructors in your non-compilable code?

Comment: @SergeyA you don't need a virtual destructor if you use `std::make_shared`

Comment: If the calculation is the only thing different consider storing a lambda as part of `classA` rather than having a `classB` or `classC`

Comment: polymorphism makes the following claim: C *is a kind of* B. Is that the case in your design?

Comment: @RichardHodges, while this is true, I would fail review for any code which relies on that instead of properly using virtual destructors.

Comment: @RichardHodges I think that you meant *`B` is-an `A`*?

Comment: @JonathanMee or that, yes :)

Comment: @Richard: Class C shares the attribute b with B. However, they are the different classes. It is a simplified model of a complex mathematical problem....

Comment: @SergeyA I think it depends on how mired in the dark ages your code reviewer is. It is a known and designed-in feature of shared_ptr, because the deleter is carried with the shared control block. Anyone who does not realise this has no business reviewing code. Furthermore, any modern (i.e. less than 10 years old) compiler will warn when virtual destructors are required but not declared.

Comment: @RichardHodges, the problem is, a class can't enforce it's usage. What if it is used not through shared_ptr, but through some other means? Unique_ptr, for example?

Comment: @SergeyA then you'll get a warning.

Comment: @RichardHodges, class is separated from it's usage. Class can be committed to a library, and usage can be an application. I stand my ground - in any polimorphic class virtual destructor is a must.

Comment: What should be the result of calling B::getct() ?

Comment: `int getbt(int t)=0;` does not compile; need `virtual`; also need `;` after class.

Comment: @Richard: Sorry for the typo; c is not defined in B, so B::getbt()=B::getct();

Comment: @SergeyA I almost agree with you - however, derive a class from std::shared_from_this<> and its ownership by a shared_ptr suddenly becomes mandated. I am digressing... I don't have a good answer for the OP - not enough information.

Comment: @SergeyA you were right - I did use a virtual destructor in the end ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... how about composition?

I have made the handle copyable, for completeness

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int f(int a, int t) {
    return a * t;
}

struct has_a
{
    int a;
};

/// when some T is not derived from has_a, its getat method will return 0
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_base_of<has_a, T>::value>* = nullptr>
int impl_getat(const T&, int t) { return 0; }

// when some T is derived from has_a, its getat method will return f(a, t)
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<has_a, T>::value>* = nullptr>
int impl_getat(const T& a, int t) { return f(a.a, t); }

// ditto for has_b
struct has_b
{
    int b;
};
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_base_of<has_b, T>::value>* = nullptr>
int impl_getbt(const T&, int t) { return 0; }
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<has_b, T>::value>* = nullptr>
int impl_getbt(const T& b, int t) { return f(b.b, t); }

// ditto for has_c
struct has_c
{
    int c;
};
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_base_of<has_c, T>::value>* = nullptr>
int impl_getct(const T&, int t) { return 0; }
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<has_c, T>::value>* = nullptr>
int impl_getct(const T& c, int t) { return f(c.c, t); }

// an object to hold the polymorphic model
struct handle
{
    // the concept that defines the operations on the model
    struct concept {
        // rule of 5 when virtual destructors are involved...
        concept() = default;
        concept(const concept&) = default;
        concept(concept&&) = default;
        concept& operator=(const concept&) = default;
        concept& operator=(concept&&) = default;
        virtual ~concept() = default;

        // cloneable concept
        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> clone() const = 0;

        // concept's interface
        virtual int getat(int t) = 0;
        virtual int getbt(int t) = 0;
        virtual int getct(int t) = 0;
    };

    // a model models the concept, by deriving from any number of discrete parts
    template<class...Parts>
    struct model : concept, Parts...
    {
        model(Parts...parts)
        : Parts(std::move(parts))...
        {}

        model(const model&) = default;

        // model the clone op
        std::unique_ptr<concept> clone() const override {
            return std::make_unique<model>(*this);
        }

        // defer to impl functions (see above) for the calculations
        int getat(int t) override { return impl_getat(*this, t); }
        int getbt(int t) override { return impl_getbt(*this, t); }
        int getct(int t) override { return impl_getct(*this, t); }
    };


    std::unique_ptr<concept> _impl;

    // interface - note: not polymorphic, so we can be stored in a container
    int getat(int t) { return _impl->getat(t); }
    int getbt(int t) { return _impl->getbt(t); }
    int getct(int t) { return _impl->getct(t); }

    // constructor - construct from parts
    template<class...Parts>
    handle(Parts...parts)
    : _impl(std::make_unique<model<std::decay_t<Parts>...>>(std::move(parts)...))
    {
    }

    // let's make it copyable

    handle(const handle& r)
    : _impl(r._impl->clone())
    {
    }
    // rule of 5 because we meddled with the copy constructor...

    handle(handle&& r) : _impl(std::move(r._impl)) {}

    handle& operator=(const handle& r) {
        _impl = r._impl->clone();
        return *this;
    }

    handle& operator=(handle&& r) = default;


};

int main()
{
    std::vector<handle> v;
    v.emplace_back(has_a{10}, has_b{12});
    v.emplace_back(has_a{1}, has_b{2}, has_c {3});

    int aa = 1;
    for (auto& x : v)
    {
        std::cout << x.getat(aa) << std::endl;
        std::cout << x.getbt(aa) << std::endl;
        std::cout << x.getct(aa) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++aa;
    }

    // prove it's copyable etc

    auto y = v.back();
    std::cout << y.getat(aa) << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.getbt(aa) << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.getct(aa++) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // and moveable

    y = handle(has_a{4}, has_b{5}, has_c{6});
    std::cout << y.getat(aa) << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.getbt(aa) << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.getct(aa++) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

expected results:

```
10
12
0

2
4
6

3
6
9

16
20
24
```

Comment: @ Richard: interesting solution with many advanced features; I have to study your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

If a default implementation not make sense in your case I prefer a pure virtual approach, this prevent at compile time to your client to misuse your class, so for 1 consider [interface classes](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/).
For 2 you should be noticed, if your client not override what is the behavior? a message in runtime, "Please implement this"...
elaborate more on 3 please...